# Changing Negative Values to 0, Without Changing other Columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a DF in which I'm analyzing customer total price. I'm finding the total price a customer paid by summing discount (since it is already a negative number) from sales value of the product.

`transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] = transaction_df_clean['sales_value'] + transaction_df_clean['coupon_disc']`

Consequently, some total prices are negative and I want to change these to 0 to avoid negative numbers.

Input:

`transaction_df_clean.loc[transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] < 0].head(10)`

Output (showing 1 row):

```
index   household_key   basket_id   day product_id  quantity    sales_value store_id    retail_disc trans_time  week_no coupon_disc coupon_match_disc   customer_price
----------
13895   988  27282152470     25  1088634    2   1.00    408 -0.98   2353    4   -1.49   0.00    -0.49
```

However, when trying to change the negative values to 0 in the "customer_price" columns, other columns that are not being targeted change to 0 too.

Input:

```
transaction_df_clean.loc[transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] < 0] = 0
transaction_df_clean.loc[transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] == 0].head(20)
```

Output:

```
index household_key basket_id   day product_id  quantity    sales_value store_id    retail_disc trans_time  week_no coupon_disc coupon_match_disc   customer_price
----------
13895   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0   0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    0.0
```

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this, `transaction_df_clean.loc[transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] < 0] = 0`, is actually doing is applying the condition to the entire dataframe and when you put `= 0` the 0 gets broadcasted to all the points of data. You're telling it to select all the rows in your dataframe where customer_price is less than 0 then change all the filtered rows to 0.

Aside from applying the condition you have to select the column/series that you want to change.

How I remember to use `.loc` is `df.loc[row filter/selection, column filter/selection]`

Another way to do it would be

`transaction_df_clean.loc[transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] < 0,'customer_price'] = 0`

There is a good section in the docs about setting values called **Setting Values**
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: Hi @fcsr, thank you for taking the time to explain what was happening when I was `.loc` the specific column.

Comment: Hi @fcsr, thank you for taking the time to explain what was happening when I was `.loc` the specific column.

Answer (score 2):

You also need select the column.

```
m = transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] < 0
transaction_df_clean.loc[m,'customer_price']=0
```

I would use [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html).

```
transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] = transaction_df_clean['customer_price'].clip(lower=0)
```

We could also use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html).

```
transaction_df_clean['customer_price']=transaction_df_clean['customer_price'].mask(m,0)
```

---

**So you need [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) + [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html)**:

```
transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] = transaction_df_clean['sales_value'].add(transaction_df_clean['coupon_disc']).clip(lower=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `numpy.max` to handle it (`pandas` also has a `max` but it's less-intuitive since it defaults to aggregating data instead of working per-row)

```
import numpy as np 

transaction_df_clean['customer_price'] = np.max(0, transaction_df_clean['sales_value'] + transaction_df_clean['coupon_disc'])
```

this way there won't be any negative numbers